# How to print the address of the underlying array of string in golang

Tags: go

I am a beginner in go language and have a problem with string:

string is defined as:

```
 type stringStruct struct{
      str unsafe.Pointer
      len int }
```

I use:

```
str := "abc"
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &str)
```

to print the struct address and I want to know how to print the address of 
underlying array of string.

I am not good at English and don't know if I express enough clearly.

thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you are a beginner: Stay away from package unsafe and reflect. You won't learn anything and it will do you no good.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [unsafe](https://godoc.org/unsafe) package to [convert](https://godoc.org/unsafe#Pointer) the string to a [reflect.StringHeader](https://godoc.org/reflect#StringHeader). The Data field of the header is the address of the backing array of bytes.

```
func stringAddr(s string) uintptr {
    return (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)).Data
}
```

Use the function like this:

```
str := "abc"
fmt.Printf("%08x\n", stringAddr(str))
```

Comment: really appreciate your help！

Comment: Worth noting, while you can access that address via the `unsafe` package, do _not_ assume that means you can change it.  The Go compiler is allowed to _assume_ that strings are constant and not necessarily update them.